# How to get all values of one specific key from an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

I am developing application using Objective C.

I am getting following array in the response from server side ( i'm using `Get` method of `AFNetworking`).

```
 Response from server: `[{"name":"option1","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option1"},{"name":"option2","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option2"},{"name":"option3","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option3"},{"name":"option4","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option4"},{"name":"option5","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option5"},{"name":"option6","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option6"},{"name":"option7","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option7"},{"name":"option8","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option8"},{"name":"option9","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option9"},{"name":"option10","profile_id":0,"profile_name":"option10"}]`
```

I want to separate values for the key `name`.

In short, i want output like:`[option1,option2,option3,option4,option5,option6,option7,option8,option9,option10]`

For that i tried like following way:

store that response in array (`_arr`). and then try to separate values for key `name` like following way,

```
   NSArray *optionArray = [_arr valueForKey:@"name"]; 
   NSLog(@"%@",optionArray);
```

but, unfortunately this is not working. Application crashes and gives following logs.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x7abd0600> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key name.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00ae2a14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x005a3e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00ae2631 -[NSException raise] + 17
    3   Foundation                          0x00239098 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 282
    4   Foundation                          0x0017a798 _NSGetUsingKeyValueGetter + 105
    5   Foundation                          0x0017a727 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 288
    6   Foundation                          0x001bac40 -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:] + 1079
    7   Foundation                          0x001ba739 -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 290
    8   Foundation                          0x001ba60f -[NSPredicate evaluateWithObject:] + 48
    9   Foundation                          0x001ba593 _filterObjectsUsingPredicate + 437
    10  Foundation                          0x001ba360 -[NSArray(NSPredicateSupport) filteredArrayUsingPredicate:] + 314
    11  Wellness_24x7                       0x0008fbc4 __31-[ForthViewController Donating]_block_invoke + 564
    12  Wellness_24x7                       0x0006c097 __116-[AFHTTPSessionManager dataTaskWithHTTPMethod:URLString:parameters:uploadProgress:downloadProgress:success:failure:]_block_invoke97 + 231
    13  Wellness_24x7                       0x00080bd5 __72-[AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate URLSession:task:didCompleteWithError:]_block_invoke_2132 + 213
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0330e377 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x033319cd _dispatch_client_callout + 14
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x03316f90 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 910
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00a33fde __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 14
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x009f1cd4 __CFRunLoopRun + 2356
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x009f10e6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x009f0efb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x050c8664 GSEventRunModal + 192
    22  GraphicsServices                    0x050c84a1 GSEventRun + 104
    23  UIKit                               0x012ecbfa UIApplicationMain + 160
    24  Wellness_24x7                       0x0006905a main + 138
    25  libdyld.dylib                       0x0335ba21 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you show some additional code

Comment: I think each element of `optionArray` is `NSDictonary` type. Use a loop to iterate.

Comment: I have no clear idea about how to do that, thats why i just do like  NSArray *optionArray = [_arr valueForKey:@"name"];  for separate all values for that key... @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @SurajSukale : Use `Krishna Kumar's` answer.

Comment: Thank you @Poles ...it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually your JSON Response started with `Array`, so do like

```
NSArray *ResponseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: KNilOptions error: nil];

NSMutableArray *finalArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *temp in ResponseArray) {
[finalArray addObject:temp[@"name"]];
 }
```

**Choice-2 for AFNetworking**

```
   NSMutableArray *finalArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *temp in responseObject) {
[finalArray addObject:temp[@"name"]];
 }
```

Comment: @SurajSukale before adding name in your Array, always check if that key is available otherwise it will cause to be crash. `if(temp[@"name"]) {[finalArray addObject:temp[@"name"]];`
 }

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
NSMutableArray *arrOptions = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i<_arr.count; i++) {
    [arrOptions addObject:[[_arr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]];
}
```

here `arrOptions` will contain your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you are getting response in JSON format. So you can convert JSON into mutable containers like Dictionary and Arrays. In your case it is array of dictionaries.

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];

if(!jsonArray)
{
  for(NSDictionary *dict in jsonArray)
  {
    NSLog(@"%@", dict valueForKey: @"name");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your JSON data below you need to store data using `NSDictionary` instead of an Array.

```
[{
    "name": "option1",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option1"
}, {
    "name": "option2",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option2"
}, {
    "name": "option3",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option3"
}, {
    "name": "option4",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option4"
}, {
    "name": "option5",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option5"
}, {
    "name": "option6",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option6"
}, {
    "name": "option7",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option7"
}, {
    "name": "option8",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option8"
}, {
    "name": "option9",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option9"
}, {
    "name": "option10",
    "profile_id": 0,
    "profile_name": "option10"
}]
```

Get the data using dict like:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDataDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
NSArray *optionArray = [jsonDataDict valueForKey:@"name"];
```

**Problem: you are trying to get data of `name` key and you storing whole `JSON` data inside an array.**

> Array doesn't contain key value pair use `NSDictionary`.

Comment: @SurajSukale most welcome, if you opt dictionary then you do not need any iteration of object and getting internal nested dict data is easy in future case.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to achieve and your thinking i can say you are on right track.
You have converted your response Data in NSDictionary but it must be an array.

```
NSArray *responseArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

this will convert your response to array and you can use

```
NSArray *optionArray = [responseArray valueForKey:@"name"];
```

This will lead to same result as answer from @Krishna Kumar but with this you will be able to avoid "for" loop.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: My pleasure...!